# Making a dip ahead of time

Tags: texture, dip

I would like to make a chunky dip using cooked broad beans, olive oil, white vinegar and Parmesan. Would mixing it together, covering and storing it in fridge for several hours in advance, keep the texture and flavours fresh?

Comment: Please could you refine the question, how long do you wish/plan to store before use?  Several hours is an ambiguous descriptor.  Definition of several: More than two, but not many.  Prior to cooking, the broad beans were raw, frozen, dried?  These details may affect the answer and the relevance.

Comment: Sounds like a hummus sort of dip? You say chunky... do you mean blended but not smooth or just whole beans?

Comment: Thanks, I agree I did not give enough info. I will use frozen beans,  cooked, shelled and forked to give a slightly mashed texture to spread on toast. I would like to cover and store in the fridge for 3 hours then bring back to room temp. to serve.

Answer (score 3):

Vinegar will start changing the flavor and texture of your dip from the moment you add it. Putting your dip in the fridge might slow down the process, but it will still happen. Is adding the vinegar right before serving your dip a possibility?

Also, keep in mind that if you want your dip's texture to be just as when you made it, you need to bring it back to room temperature before serving it. Olive oil in particular can coagulate at low temperatures, so keep that in mind.

Comment: And the starches from the beans behave much differently when cold than when warm ... but overheating might cause problems with the cheese.